# polkit on OpenBSD

Tags: debian, openbsd, bsd, polkit

I use xfce which came with a polkit action org.xfce.thunar.policy in /usr/local/share/polkit-1/actions/.
This action allow to run thunar as root if you can give the root password.
On debian with pkexec version 0.105, you create a desktop file on the desk like this one :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Thunar pkexec
Comment=Lance Thunar sous root
Exec=pkexec thunar /
Icon=Thunar
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
```

This way, you get a window like this one :

[image: polkit authenticate]

If you give the password you get :

[image: thunar as root]

On OpenBSD with pkexec version 0.116, nothing happend.

This 2 versions of polkit don't work the same way.
With version 0.105, on debian, you can create a pkla file to modify the authorizations.
With version 0.116, on OpenBSD, you must create a rules file to run the action.
So I create a rules file to run the action.

```
cat 30-thunar_pkexec.rules
polkit.addRule (function (action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.xfce.thunar")
  {
    return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
  }
});
```

And nothing happen.
If i set the return line like this :

```
return polkit.Result.YES;
```

I get :

[image: thunar as root on OpenBSD]
So this work without authentification but it's not what I want.
How to get this authenticate window with polkit 0.116 ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the policy file on Debian is in /usr/local/share/polkit-1/actions and not /usr/share/polkit-1/actions? It appears that only /usr/share/polkit-1/actions is supported, even on Linux. There have been calls from users to allow /usr/local/share/polkit-1/actions too, but so far it doesn't seem to have happened (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/issues/51)